# Openswan Cisco ASA 9.1 -- cannot resopnd to IPsec SA request because no connection is known for

Tags: cisco-asa, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, openswan

Ok, so I have a simple VPN IPSEC setup with a single Linux host that has a public IP address and a loopback interface of 172.16.255.1. On the right side I have a Cisco ASA 5505 9.1. the issue is the Cisco ASA says when debugging "PHASE 2 Completed" so i know there is no conflict with my ISKMP negotiation. However I am receiving the following which should indicates a Network ACL mismatch, but I cannot figure it out.

```
Apr 09 14:30:26 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = x.x.137.133, IP = x.x.137.133, IKE got a KEY_ADD msg for SA: SPI = 0x61af9f82
Apr 09 14:30:26 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = x.x.137.133, IP = x.x.137.133, Pitcher: received KEY_UPDATE, spi 0x95cad3f0
Apr 09 14:30:26 [IKEv1 DEBUG]Group = x.x.137.133, IP = x.x.137.133, Starting P2 rekey timer: 27360 seconds.
Apr 09 14:30:26 [IKEv1]Group = x.x.137.133, IP = x.x.137.133, PHASE 2 COMPLETED (msgid=0504e77c)
Apr 09 14:23:29 [IKEv1]Group = x.x.137.133, IP = x.x.137.133, Received non-routine Notify message: Invalid ID info (18)
```

And on the Linux box running OpenSwan I see:

```
"L2L-IPSEC-CT" #1: the peer proposed: 172.16.255.1/32:0/0 -> 192.168.0.0/24:0/0
"L2L-IPSEC-CT" #1: cannot respond to IPsec SA request because no connection is known for 172.16.255.1/32===x.x.137.133<x.x.137.133>[+S=C]:1/0...x.x.157.15<x.x.157.15>[+S=C]:1/0===192.168.0.0/24
"L2L-IPSEC-CT" #1: sending encrypted notification INVALID_ID_INFORMATION to x.x.157.15:500
```

After doing some reseach it seems to be an issue with the proposed Networks allowed to traverse the tunnel. however my configs on both are the sames

**Cisco config**

```
access-list VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1 line 1 extended permit icmp 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 host 172.16.255.1 (hitcnt=422) 0x150f2cfc
access-list VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1 line 2 extended permit ip 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 host 172.16.255.1 (hitcnt=42) 0xfd98dbac
```

**Openswan Config**

```
conn L2L-IPSEC-CT
        auto=start #automatically start if detected
        type=tunnel #tunnel mode/not transport
        compress=no

        ###THIS SIDE###
        left=x.x.137.133
        leftsubnet=172.16.255.1/32

        ###PEER SIDE###
        right=x.x.157.15
        rightsubnet=192.168.0.0/24

        #phase 1 encryption-integrity-diffhellman
        keyexchange=ike
        ike=3des-md5-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024
        ikelifetime=86400s
        authby=secret #use presharedkey

        #phase 2 encryption-pfsgroup
        phase2=esp #esp for encryption | ah for authentication only
        phase2alg=3des-md5;modp1024
        pfs=no
```

My test has been a ping from 192.168.0.200 toward 172.16.255.1:
Here is the show crypto ipsec sa

```
asa(config)# show crypto ipsec sa
interface: outside
    Crypto map tag: outside-cmap, seq num: 40, local addr: x.x.157.15

      access-list VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1 extended permit ip 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 host 172.16.255.1
      local ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
      remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (172.16.255.1/255.255.255.255/0/0)
      current_peer: x.x.137.133

      #pkts encaps: 0, #pkts encrypt: 0, #pkts digest: 0
      #pkts decaps: 0, #pkts decrypt: 0, #pkts verify: 0
      #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
      #pkts not compressed: 0, #pkts comp failed: 0, #pkts decomp failed: 0
      #pre-frag successes: 0, #pre-frag failures: 0, #fragments created: 0
      #PMTUs sent: 0, #PMTUs rcvd: 0, #decapsulated frgs needing reassembly: 0
      #TFC rcvd: 0, #TFC sent: 0
      #Valid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0, #Invalid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0
      #send errors: 0, #recv errors: 0

      local crypto endpt.: x.x.157.15/0, remote crypto endpt.: x.x.137.133/0
      path mtu 1500, ipsec overhead 58(36), media mtu 1500
      PMTU time remaining (sec): 0, DF policy: copy-df
      ICMP error validation: disabled, TFC packets: disabled
      current outbound spi: 61AF9F82
      current inbound spi : 95CAD3F0
```

Open swan ipsec auto --status

```
**000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT": 172.16.255.1/32===x.x.137.133<x.x.137.133>[+S=C]...x.x.157.15<x.x.157.15>[+S=C]===192.168.0.0/24; erouted; eroute owner: #4
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":     myip=unset; hisip=unset;
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":   ike_life: 86400s; ipsec_life: 28800s; rekey_margin: 540s; rekey_fuzz: 100%; keyingtries: 0
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":   policy: PSK+ENCRYPT+TUNNEL+UP+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK+lKOD+rKOD; prio: 32,24; interface: eth0;
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":   newest ISAKMP SA: #3; newest IPsec SA: #4;
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":   IKE algorithms wanted: 3DES_CBC(5)_000-MD5(1)_000-MODP1024(2), AES_CBC(7)_256-SHA1(2)_000-MODP1024(2); flags=-strict
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":   IKE algorithms found:  3DES_CBC(5)_192-MD5(1)_128-MODP1024(2), AES_CBC(7)_256-SHA1(2)_160-MODP1024(2)
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":   IKE algorithm newest: 3DES_CBC_192-MD5-MODP1024
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":   ESP algorithms wanted: 3DES(3)_000-MD5(1)_000; pfsgroup=MODP1024(2); flags=-strict
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":   ESP algorithms loaded: 3DES(3)_192-MD5(1)_128
000 "L2L-IPSEC-CT":   ESP algorithm newest: 3DES_000-HMAC_MD5; pfsgroup=<N/A>
000
000 #4: "L2L-IPSEC-CT":500 STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 27518s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner; isakmp#3; idle; import:admin initiate
000 #4: "L2L-IPSEC-CT" esp.95cad3f0@x.x.157.15 esp.61af9f82@x.x.137.133 tun.0@x.x.157.15 tun.0@x.x.137.133 ref=0 refhim=4294901761
000 #3: "L2L-IPSEC-CT":500 STATE_MAIN_I4 (ISAKMP SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 85221s; newest ISAKMP; lastdpd=1s(seq in:0 out:0); idle; import:admin initiate
**
```

I'm really lost as to why this isn't working. Perhaps a new set of eyes, since I've been working on this for 3 days! Yikes!

Appreciate your help **serverfault** community!

P.S. Is there any OpenSwan commands i can use to verify the subnets in question are being picked up by the tunnel "openswan"

Comment: is pfs disabled on the asa? what 9.1 version is on the asa? there are a lot of vpn bugs in 9.1(1)

Comment: pfs is disabled on Openswan and Cisco ASA. Cisco ASA version 9.1(3). I have pings working when originating ont eh Cisco ASA side, but I can't ping anything from the Openswan side. So weird.

Comment: adding leftsidesourceip helped with issues of One Direction Pings.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I beliveve I figured it out.

So even though my Openswan box is **not** behind a NAT, and has a direct NIC with a public IP I had to turn on NAT-Traversal. With this in mind I had to add **leftsoureip=172.16.255.1** to tell Openswan what source address to use when communicating with the right side of the Tunnel. The last thing I had to do was to enable **forceencaps**. For some reason as soon as I did this the tunnel started working.

```
config setup
     listen=x.x.137.133
     nat_traversal=yes
     virtual_private=%v:172.16.255.1/32,192.168.0.0/24
     oe=off
     protostack=netkey

conn L2L-IPSEC-CT
    auto=start #automatically start if detected
    type=tunnel #tunnel mode/not transport
    compress=no

    ###THIS SIDE###
    left=x.x.137.133
    leftid=x.x.137.133
    leftsubnet=172.16.255.1/32
    leftsourceip=172.16.255.1

    ###PEER SIDE###
    right=x.x.157.15
    rightid=x.x.157.15
    rightsubnet=192.168.0.0/24

    #phase 1 encryption-integrity-diffhellman
    keyexchange=ike
    ike=3des-md5-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024
    ikelifetime=86400s
    authby=secret #use presharedkey

    #phase 2 encryption-pfsgroup
    phase2=esp #esp for encryption | ah for authentication only
    phase2alg=3des-md5;modp1024
    pfs=no
    forceencaps=yes
```