# Trying to replicate a working IPSec/L2TP config from OpenSWAN to StrongSWAN

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

I have a working OpenSWAN implementation for RA, using IPsec transport and l2tp for the tunnel, running in AWS. The instance has a private IP, with a public EIP mapped to it.

I use the private ip for the `left` and `leftsubnet` parameters and the public in the `leftid`.

I am now trying to configure an IPSec connection from the same client to a new endpoint, which is running StrongSWAN (4.5.2). I have tried to replicate the config from openswan to strongswan as much as possible. For now, I am only trying to get the IPSec set up (not worrying about l2tp just yet), and am having trouble with phase 2 (phase 1 is completing ok).

The differences in config are:

```
--- openswan.conf       2014-07-18 11:48:01.740966015 +0200
+++ strongswan.conf     2014-07-18 11:46:58.927569703 +0200
@@ -1,11 +1,14 @@
+version 2.0
+
config setup
-       protostack=netkey
+       charonstart=no
+       interfaces="%none"
        nat_traversal=yes
-       virtual_private=%v4:192.168.10.0/24
        oe=off
-       nhelpers=0
-       interfaces=%defaultroute
+       virtual_private="%v4:192.168.11.0/24"
+
+conn %default
+       keyexchange=ikev1

conn remote-access
        forceencaps=yes
        type=transport
        ike=3des-sha1
-       phase2alg=3des-sha1
```

When I bring up the connection from my client, I get the following:

```
003 "myconn" #1: NAT-Traversal: Result using RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal): both are NATed
108 "myconn" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
004 "myconn" #1: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=OAKLEY_PRESHARED_KEY cipher=aes_128 prf=oakley_sha group=modp2048}
117 "myconn" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: initiate
```

And in the server logs

```
"remote-access"[3] 105.1.1.1 #2: NAT-Traversal: Result using RFC 3947: both are NATed
"remote-access"[3] 105.1.1.1 #2: Peer ID is ID_IPV4_ADDR: '192.168.2.2'
"remote-access"[4] 105.1.1.1 #2: deleting connection "remote-access" instance with peer client.ip.addr {isakmp=#0/ipsec=#0}
"remote-access"[4] 105.1.1.1:4500 #2: sent MR3, ISAKMP SA established
"remote-access"[4] 105.1.1.1:4500 #2: cannot respond to IPsec SA request because no connection is known for 54.1.1.1/32===10.0.0.2:4500[54.1.1.1]:17/1701...105.1.1.1.1:4500[192.168.2.2]:17/%any==={192.168.2.2/32}
"remote-access"[4] 105.1.1.1:4500 #2: sending encrypted notification INVALID_ID_INFORMATION to 105.1.1.1:4500
```

192.168.2.2 is the private IP of the client and 105.1.1.1 is the public IP that it gets NAT'd to.

I have searched around for "cannot respond to IPsec SA request because no connection is known for" and only come up with 1 relating to strongswan at https://lists.strongswan.org/pipermail/users/2011-July/001885.html, as well as [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/587872/openswan-cisco-asa-9-1-cannot-resopnd-to-ipsec-sa-request-because-no-connecti) but neither of the suggestions work (adjusting rightid on the peer or adding leftsourceip on the strongswan server).

The peer / client that I am connecting to strongswan with is libreswan 3.7

**edit** here's the configs

StrongSWAN in EC:

`conn remote-access
  authby=secret
  pfs=no
  left=10.0.0.2
  leftid=54..1.1.1
  leftsubnet=10.0.0.2/32
  leftnexthop=%defaultroute
  leftprotoport=17/1701
  right=%any
  rightid=%any
  rightsubnetwithin=0.0.0.0/0
  rightprotoport=17/%any
  type=transport
  forceencaps=yes
  auto=add
  ike=3des-sha1
  dpddelay=15
  dpdtimeout=45
  dpdaction=clear
  auth=esp
  esp=aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!`

The secrets file on this host:

```
54.1.1.1 %any : PSK "XXX"
```

My local RA client config:

`conn myconn
        authby=secret
        pfs=no
        rekey=yes
        keyingtries=3
        type=transport
        left=%defaultroute
        leftprotoport=17/1701
        right=54.1.1.1
        rightprotoport=17/1701
        auto=add
        phase2=esp
        phase2alg=3des-md5;modp1024
        forceencaps=yes`

secrets:

```
0.0.0.0 %any 54.1.1.1 : PSK "XXX"
```

I recently added the phase2 parameters and forceencaps on my local client.

The diffs shown earlier were between 2 EC2-based hosts that I am connecting to. The "myconn" connection is from my workstation, and I have 2 conns, 1 for the openswan peer (which works) and a copy of it for the strongswan peer (which doesn't). I figured using the same approach for left / right configurations would result in a working config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working config using openswan. Some of the parameters that had an impact on getting this config working were using `rightsubnetwithin` and `phase2alg` (phase2alg can be adjusted as needed, I initially used 3des-sha1, but adjusted later).

**example configs**

`/etc/ipsec.conf`

```
config setup
    plutostderrlog= "/var/log/pluto.err"
    protostack=netkey
    nat_traversal=yes
    virtual_private=%v4:192.168.10.0/24
    oe=off
    nhelpers=0
    interfaces=%defaultroute

conn remote-access
    auto=add
    left=10.0.0.2
    leftid=54.1.1.1
    leftsubnet=10.0.0.2/32
    leftnexthop=%defaultroute
    leftprotoport=17/1701
    rightprotoport=17/%any
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightsubnetwithin=0.0.0.0/0
    forceencaps=yes
    authby=secret
    pfs=no
    type=transport
    auth=esp
    ike=3des-sha1
    phase2alg=3des-sha1
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=60
    dpdtimeout=500
```

`/etc/ipsec.secrets`

```
54.1.1.1 %any : PSK "Your_PSK"
```

That got the IPSec transport up.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, one or both endpoints here have RFC1918 addresses, which are behind NAT devices.

You can read more details in [an earlier answer of mine](https://serverfault.com/questions/386000/ipsec-vpn-site-to-site-how-should-i-configure-the-ipsec-conf-files-on-both-site/386623#386623), but the upshot is that it breaks the symmetry of the conf file.  Instead of each side having the same `left=` and `right=` endpoints, and letting SWAN sort out which is which, each side must have **its own private** ip address, and **the other side's public** one.  It still doesn't matter which is `left` and which is `right` on any given end, but the two addresses will be different from the two on the other.

You haven't posted your actual `.conf` file, only the diffs, so I can't comment further, but I very strongly suspect that this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have added the update. I have added the config to see if there is anything obvious I am overlooking. This is not a site to site connection, but rather a client to site connection.

Comment: From SWAN's point of view, there is no difference between those two types of connection; one just routes a /32 which is its own address.  Thanks for the update; does `left` really own the IP address `54.1.1.1` (ie, does it have on one of its own interfaces the real address that you have redacted as `54.1.1.1`)?

Comment: 54.1.1.1 is an EIP, no it's not on the left. left has 1 interface (eth0) which has 10.0.0.2 on it and AWS handles the NAT for 54.1.1.1 to 10.0.0.2. That's why I am using it for `leftid` only and not `left`. I can remove the `leftid` param from the left side and add `rightid=10.0.0.2` to the right side and that also works to get past phase 1. However, I end up with the same rror when i start phase 2.

Comment: Without `leftid` on the left or `rightid` on the right, I get an error: `we require peer to have ID '54.1.1.1', but peer declares '10.0.0.2'`

Comment: What about with just `leftid=` on the right, and `rightid=` on the left, each specifying the *private* IP address of the other?

Comment: i switched from strongswan to openswan and used the same parameters that I previously had (specifically containing `phase2alg` parameter and phase 2 passes.

Comment: OK.  And the results of this change?

Comment: i have a working connection.

Comment: **Well done** - hearty congratulations!  If you feel like writing up exactly what you did, in a single linear narrative with configs included, as an answer, it may help someone who comes along in the future.  You can also accept your answer (though the site may make you wait a short while), which will stop this question floating around forever like a querulous albatross.  And I'll upvote it.

Comment: Thanks @madhatter. I've posted the solution. Appreciate your input in getting there :)